# How to call gRPC server methods from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, grpc

I have a NET Core cross-platform gRPC server. 
Is it possible to call its methods from PowerShell? How to?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Grpc provides cli client to call the server. Your server should have dynamic discovery service exposed.
See https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/command_line_tool.md

Comment: @ZedZip https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/command_line_tool.md

Comment: Thanx, but I am trying to find a PowerShell script, i.e. how to .

Comment: If you want to implement grpc cmdlet, instead of calling grpc cli from power shell- go ahead

Comment: Another option is to call grpc service via grpc web proxy using rest calls from power shell